# unwrapping an Optional value error - Checking Receipt Response For In App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

On app start up im checking the receipt status of an auto renew in app purchase:

App delgate

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            println("Check for receipt on background queue")

 self.CheckReciptStatus()

}


 func CheckReciptStatus(){

    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?

    var receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
    println("reciptUrl: '\(receiptUrl)'")

    //
    // Nil error on this line
    //
    var receipt: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL:receiptUrl!, options: nil, error: nil)!
    //



    var receiptdata: NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    println(receiptdata)


    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.someurl.uk/verifyReceipt.php")!)

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?

    request.HTTPBody = receiptdata.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)


    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        if(err != nil)
        {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {

            //
            // ---Recipt data ---
            //
            if let parseJSON = json {

                if parseJSON["status"] as? Int == 0 {
                   println("Sucessfully returned purchased receipt data")
                }
                else{
                    println("Receipt error")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "subscribed")

                }

                // Get latest expiry date
                if let receiptInfo: NSArray = parseJSON["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {
                   let lastReceipt = receiptInfo.lastObject as! NSDictionary

                    // Get last recipt
                    println("LAST RECIPT INFORMATION \n",lastReceipt)

                    // Format date
                    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
                    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

                    // Get Expiry date as NSDate
                    let subscriptionExpirationDate: NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(lastReceipt["expires_date"] as! String) as NSDate!
                    println("\n   - DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = \(subscriptionExpirationDate)")

                    println("   - CURRENT DATE = \(NSDate())")

                    //
                    // --- Subscription Status ----
                    //
                    if subscriptionExpirationDate.timeIntervalSinceNow < 0.0 {

                        // Date has passed
                        println("\n         ->  SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRED \n ")
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "subscribed")
                    }
                    else{

                        println("\n         ->  SUBSCRIBED \n")
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "subscribed")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Receipt Error: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()

  }
}
```

Get receipt info

```
var receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
```

Prints:

> reciptUrl:
>   'Optional(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D0C4DAF0-952F-4C29-9D94-B68DB1FF036F/StoreKit/sandboxReceipt)'

```
 var receipt: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL:receiptUrl!, options: nil, error: nil)!
```

Produces error

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Even though i'm getting the `storekit receipt url`.  So this leads to believe it's because of the force unwrapping in `var receipt`.  Ok, so when I then try to change the line to

```
var receipt: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL:receiptUrl?, options: nil, error: nil)?
```

Im just told that `NSData` is not unwrapped `did I mean "!" or "??"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A check if the receipt exists using

```
var fileExists = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(receiptUrl!.path!)
if fileExists {
    println("Appstore Receipt already exists")
}
```

Sorts it

Answer (score 0):

Postfix `!` causes *force unwrapping*.

Postfix `?` is used for *optional chaining*. This means, if the result of the expression before the `?` is not `nil`, the next expression in the chain will be evaluated. The result of an optional-chain is always an `Optional` though - because any expression along the chain may result in `nil`.
Using the postfix `?` operator on one expression is therefore useless, as it returns the expression itself.

`??` is the *nil-coalescing operator*. This operator is syntactical sugar, replacing a common pattern with the ternary operator:

```
return myOptional ?? defaultResult
```

Is the same as:

```
return (myOptional != nil) ? myOptional! : defaultResult
```

Which is the same as:

```
if myOptional != nil {
    return myOptional!
} else {
    return defaultResult
}
```

If you wanted to use this operator you would therefore have to provide a default value, which is used if your `Optional` is in fact `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for reply and explaination, ok checking this now

Comment: Im not getting any nil value when I call my `var receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL` so i still dont understand why im getting a nil error?

Comment: Could you pass me the whole chunk of code? That might make it easier to understand.

Comment: ok dang. I'm out of time right now. I'll come back to this later if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Marcus yes it would